# Генерация меню WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно сделать, чтобы меню генерировалось следующим способом: вместо тега "a" был тег "div". Ссылка записывалась в data-href='www.site.com', а название страницы в этом теге. Как и в каком файле можно реализовать такую идею?

```html
<!--  например вордпресс выдаст вот такую структуру меню -->
<div class="nav">
   <ul>
      <li>
         <a href="www.site.com">Title Link</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
<!-- а нужно чтобы выдал вот такую -->
<div class="nav">
   <ul>
      <li>
         <div data-href='www.site.com'>Title Link</div>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

И можно сделать, чтобы была галочка, чтобы можно было выбирать каким способом размещать ссылку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML-код меню можно поправить фильтром.

Добавьте в functions.php темы.

```
/**
 * Filters the HTML list content for navigation menus.
 *
 * @param string   $items The HTML list content for the menu items.
 * @param stdClass $args  An object containing wp_nav_menu() arguments.
 *
 * @return string
 */
function wp_nav_menu_items_action( $items, $args ) {
    $items = str_replace( '<a href=', '<div data-href=', $items );
    $items = str_replace( '</a>', '</div>', $items );

    return $items;
}

add_action( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'wp_nav_menu_items_action', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Спасибо большое